# Django template and variable {% if x == "about" %} does not work

Tags: django

How to check if `x` variable is == "about" string?

I try:

```
{% for x in p %}
    {% if x == "about" %}
        <a href="/about/">About</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ x }}` = about

but does not work (content of `if` is not displayed)

EDIT:

```
def search(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        if len(term) > 3:
            p = Chunk.objects.filter(Q(content__contains=term) | Q(
                key__contains=term))
            count = p.count()
            return render_to_response('search_result.html',
                {'p': p, 'count': count},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    ....
```

`Chunk` is from django-chunks app

`p` i `key` from this:

```
class Chunk(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(_(u'Key'), help_text=_(u"A unique name for this chunk of content"), blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(_(u'Content'), blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(_(u'Description'), blank=True, max_length=64, help_text=_(u"Short Description"))
```

Comment: Where did the value came from? your views

Comment: Please,show what is p in format familiar to JSON.

Try to use x.content == 'about'.

Comment: @EllochkaCannibal `x.content == 'about'` work fine. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
{% for x in p %}
    {% ifequal x "about" %}
        <a href="/about/">About</a>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**
p is QuerySet, so x is instance of model. You should specify the attribute containing text to compare.

Comment: That's identical to x == "about".

Comment: @user2174083,please update your post to show us what is p or though x which you expect should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `p` is an object, not a property, therefore you cannot compare the string value "about" to the object `p`. If `p` had a property, say "name", you could do:

```
{% if p.name == "about" %}
```